# Behavior of octal numbers in c++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

In C++, if we enter a number through console (cin) and start a number with zero it hold octal base.
But could one variable hold more than two values?

For example entering the following values:

```
    03 => 3 (Octal)
    012 => 10
```

But when we enter

```
    0180
    It give answer in 2 lines when output the variable (cout):
    1
    80

    and 01188 gives
    9
    88
```

Now, I know octal base have values from 0 to 7
So what is going here?
Is one variable storing more than 2 values or the compiler just freaks out because we put 8 in our input?

I am using turbo C 7 by Akki compiler.

Comment: It's reading as much octal as it can.

Comment: Elephant in room: Why are you using a 25 year old C compiler? History of computing course?

Answer (score 11):

`0180` is an octal one followed by a decimal eighty. `01188` is an octal nine followed by a decimal eighty-eight. Any character that is not legal octal marks the end of an octal number. Any character that is not legal decimal marks the end of a decimal number.

In follow ups, it seems that you don't have a good grasp of the difference between numbers and representations of numbers. Consider the number of fingers you (most likely) have. This number can be represented as "ten", "10", "the number of fingers you have", and many other ways. But it is still the same number regardless of how you represent it.

Decimal and octal are ways for representing an unlimited number of numerical values with a limited number of distinct symbols. To represent a number in source code or as input or output to a computer program, some representation has to be used.

Understanding the difference between numbers and representations of numbers is critical to being a proficient programmer and having enough math knowledge to do this comfortably is essential.

Comment: Thank you David for your wise answer.
I want to ask something here.
"You said 01188 is an octal 9"
But octal are only from 0 to 7 so how 9 ?

Comment: You are confusing digits (the symbols like '0' and '7') with numbers (things like how many fingers you have). Decimal and octal are systems for representing number values with symbols. Any integer can be represented in decimal as a string of digits from '0' to '9' and any integer can be represented in octal as a string of digits from '0' to '7'. *See update.*

Comment: I should have said, "01188 is an octal nine" to avoid confusion. Updated.